# Android studio1.0 Can't New android Project

Tags: android-studio

when i update my android studio version 1.0,i try to new a project,but it changed,

> let me choose:java,maven,gradle,groovy,griffon,static web

,so i think choose Gradle,Next,just a empty project,so maybe i should new a module, but also the module is empty too, i just want to new a android project. what should i do?Thanks, i'm the beginner for the studio.

> File->New Project->Gradle->default gradle wrapper->empty project

Answer (score 0):

> i try unload the AS ,it doesn't work,so i try reset the AS, it worked.